# Differentiating composite function involving sin(1/x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

For $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+2x^2\sin(1/x),  & \text{if $x \ne$ 0} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$ }
\end{cases}$$
I need to show that $f'(0)>0$ but also that $f$ is not increasing in any interval around 0. I don't know how to find the derivative of $f$ at 0 because $f'(x)$ is undefined at that point. As to the second part of the problem (showing that $f$ is not increasing in any interval around 0) I simply do not know where to start in order to prove this. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: For the first part use the definition of the derivative with the limit to define the function derivative around zero.

Comment: Hint: $f'(0)$ is defined.

Comment: Not interested in acknowledging/commenting/voting the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

To compute $f'(0),$ go back to the definition of derivative:

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}.$$

You should be able to figure out this limit.  (Where the formula refers to $f(h),$ $h$ is non-zero, so we're in the first case of your definition.)

$$ $$

To show that $f$ isn't increasing in any interval around $0,$ you could try to find arbitrarily small positive $x$ such that $f(x)\lt 0.$

$$ $$

By the way, you claimed that $f'(x)$ is undefined at $x=0.$  That's not true.  (What you probably mean is that the formula that you get when you work out $\,f'(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ is not defined at $x=0,$ but that's not the same as computing $\,f'(0).)$